# Repaint Image to existing JPanel with Button in JFrame?

Tags: java, image, jpanel, repaint

I'm trying to repaint an image to existing JPanel which i created by drag and drop in JFrame when the button clicked.

Here's the code:

```
package photo;


import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;


import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;


public class ImageFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

  public ImageFrame() {

      initComponents();

   }

public class ImagePanel extends JPanel{

    public BufferedImage image;

    public ImagePanel() {
       try {                
         image = ImageIO.read(new File("Vampire-full.jpg"));
       } catch (IOException ex) {
            // handle exception...
       }
    }
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);      
    }

}      


    @Override
    public Component add(Component cmpnt) {
        return super.add(cmpnt); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }



    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        Image123 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        Import = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout Image123Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(Image123);
        Image123.setLayout(Image123Layout);
        Image123Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            Image123Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 473, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        Image123Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            Image123Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 327, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        Import.setText("Import");
        Import.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                ImportActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(Image123, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(85, 85, 85)
                .addComponent(Import)
                .addGap(0, 24, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(Image123, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(Import)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void ImportActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
       Image123.repaint();

    }                                      


    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ImageFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ImageFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ImageFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ImageFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
               // new ImageFrame().setVisible(true);
                new ImageFrame().setVisible(true);

            }

        });
    }





    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JPanel Image123;
    private javax.swing.JButton Import;
    // End of variables declaration                   



}
```

But the JPanel won't show anything when i clicked the button.
I already created the JPanel (Image123) Size by dragging it with mouse.
How to fix this?

Sorry if the question looks stupid. I'm just trying to learn and need guide how to do it.

Comment: when you offer this code, neither `Import`nor `Image123` is initialized. And your actionEvent are not mapped into anywhere...

Comment: For a better an sooner help provide a [MCVE]. It's hard to tell without seeing your full code, but it seems that you are adding a pure java JPanel named `Image123` to your frame but the actual panel which is painting the image on itself is the one called `ImagePanel ` but there is no sign of it's usage and where you added it to your JFrame.

Comment: @MartinFrank Edited. Could you please give a hint how to initialize those?

Comment: @STaefi I would be glad if someone could help with the code. I'm new to Java.

Comment: @Rainzo78: you want help you should provide a [MCVE]. At least post a full code. No one can help without seeing your `initComponent()` codes or any other parts of your code (if exists any).

Comment: There are so many possible problems with this. How do you add your JPanel to your JFrame? What layout is your JFrame using? What does dragging and dropping have to do with anything here?

Comment: @STaefi That is already my full code. Edited

Comment: @Rainzo78: change `Image123 = new javax.swing.JPanel();` into `Image123 = new ImagePanel();`. As I mentioned before you are adding `Image123` of type `JPanel` instead of your customized `ImagePanel`

Comment: @STaefi but what if i wanted to use the pre-existed Image123 instead of creating the new JPanel? Should i change ImagePanel to Image123?
As if i'm try to implement Image123.setBackground(Color.Yellow); to the button, and the Image123 colour changed to yellow.

Comment: @Rainzo78: I didn't get you, but it's obvious that your implemented the painting of image in the `ImagePanel`. So if you use the pure java `JPanel` it doesn't know how to draw your custom image.

Comment: @STaefi May i ask for personal chat please? English is not my first language so it may looks confused if i explain it here.

In short: I only want my image repainted in that `Image123` panel. That `ImagePanel` thing is just thing i found from internet, because i don't know how to initialize the `Image123`.

Comment: @Rainzo78: See my answer.

Comment: There is no real question, but maybe https://gist.github.com/javagl/4dc0382be7bcb7eaefe7bc65de70e70e is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your question and your comments I can say you don't want to use any other class than the `JPanel` to show your image. Let's explain a bit about drawing on `JPanel` to lower your worries about `ImagePanel`.

As far as I know when you want to show an image in a `JPanel` you have not many choices and you should draw that image on your panel. To do that you should get the `Graphics` object of that `JPanel` in order to be able to paint your image or text etc. on that panel. Then by reading the method signatures of `JPanel` you can see some method have that graphics object as their input argument one of which is `void paintComponent(Graphics g)`. As you can infer from its name it is responsible for painting whatever is going to be shown on the panel. So by overriding it and painting our custom image using the `graphics` object we can achieve the goal.

The `ImagePanel` class you've found on internet is doing exactly what you need to do because when we want to override a method from `JPanel` the only way is to extend `JPanel` and that's what `ImagePanel` does. So I don't get what's the reason you want to avoid using `ImagePanel` since it is nothing but a `JPanel` with an overrided method `paintComponent`. So to make your code works you should change it like this:

```
private void initComponents() {

    Image123 = new ImagePanel();

    // ... your other codes ...
}
```

But if you insist on not naming it `ImagePanel`, you can do it by overriding it in an inline way. So in your `initComponents()` where you are instantiating your `Image123 = new JPanel();` you should change it this way:

```
private void initComponents() {

    Image123 = new JPanel() {
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g); // Let the panel do whatever it was doing before.

            BufferedImage image = null;             
            try {                
                image = ImageIO.read(new File("Vampire-full.jpg"));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                   // handle exception...
            }

            g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);      
        }
    };
    // ... your other codes ...
}
```

As you can see these are the same codes you had it in `ImagePanel` and the only thing changed here is the name and I can tell having a named class for doing this job is more elegant than the above inline implementation. Now it's your choice to pick which one.

Once you got the idea, you should know that `paintComponent` is a method that is called so many times during the first creation of the panel, every time you resize the frame, iconify/deiconify etc. phases and loading that image inside the `paintComponent` is bad. So either you should do as done in `ImagePanel` or to load that image in a place that is being loaded only once.

Hope this would be helpful.

Comment: You should **not** load the image (using `ImageIO`) each time when the component is repainted. It should only be loaded *once*.

Comment: @Marco13: I know that, as Rainzo78 is a newbie in java and swing I'm just trying to show what's the difference between extending `JPanel` as a named class or just inline to override the `paintComponent` method. I know you are right about loading the image and I know `paintComponent` is being called so many times but I just trying to keep it as simple as possible for him/her to get the idea. Because he is worried about using the code he found on the internet and I just tried to show that `ImagePanel` is nothing but a `JPanel`.

Comment: The code is obviously this auto-generated stuff from a UI builder, and that's not the right path to learning Swing anyhow. I do *not* downvote your answer, because you at least tried to explain some Swing concepts, but in general, I think that questions like this should not be answered at all, because it will not be useful for future visitors. (In fact, it's not even a real question, in the spirit of stackoverflow)

Comment: @Marco13: You are right, I just edited the answer and other than that you are right about the spirit of such questions. It's obvious that the main code is generated by a swing designer most likely the netbeans. The code that he/she was claiming to found on the internet is only the `ImagePanel` class. After all, I just answered to avoid getting into a chat. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Although i don't fully understand it, i will give it a several try. Thank you!

Comment: @Marco13: I'm sorry for the too-obvious question. I'll try to learn the basics before asking a question in the future.